# find (this) without performing an event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple divs with a class of type-aud. The divs don't have an ID. I can't perform a click function and then use (this) as it has to be on page load.

Each div has a attribute called file which I'm assigning to a variable and then placing it into an html5 audio tag. I need the SRC to be unique to the div.

```
    var item = $('.type-aud');
        path = item.attr('file'),
        html = '<audio controls><source src="'+path+'" type="audio/mpeg" class="audio"></audio>',
        playerClass = item.find('.audio');

    if (!playerClass.hasClass('audio')) {
        item.append(html);          
    }
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What do you want ?

Comment: *"I can't perform a click function and then use (this) ..."*, use `$(".type-aud").each(function() { /* this */ });` then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) where you'd otherwise use `.click()`.

```
$('.type-aud').each(function ()
{
    var item = $(this);
    // audio tag business here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.type-aud').each(function(i,ele) {
    var item = $(ele),
        path = item.attr('file'),
        html = '<audio controls><source src="'+path+'" type="audio/mpeg" class="audio"></audio>',
        playerClass = item.find('.audio');

    if (!playerClass.is('.audio')) item.append(html);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop on all divs having class .type-aud and then pick its file attribute

```
$('.type-aud').each(function() {
 var item = $(this);
        path = item.attr('file'),
        html = '<audio controls><source src="'+path+'" type="audio/mpeg" class="audio"></audio>',
        playerClass = item.find('.audio');

    if (!playerClass.hasClass('audio')) {
        item.append(html);          
    }
});
```